# AngularJS ng-repeat combined with ng-click=orderByField

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.orderByField = 'firstName';
$scope.reverseSort = false;
$scope.headers = ['First Name':'firstName','Last Name':'lastName']
```

**View**

```
<th
    ng-repeat="(key,value) in headers"
    ng-click="orderByField=value; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
    {{ key }}
    <span ng-show="orderByField == value">
        <span ng-show="!reverseSort"> &#9652</span>
        <span ng-show="reverseSort"> &#9662</span>
    </span>
</th>
```

This is my code, I'm trying to create all `table` headers from the list of keys in `$scope.headers` and make each header sortable.

for some reason this code doesn't work, I don't get any errors in web console either.

Comment: please put it into the plunker: http://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the problem with nested scopes. Read about the nested scope problem in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes.

Regarding how you fix it to create an object and use values from there:

```
$scope.modelData = {};
$scope.modelData.orderByField = 'firstName';
$scope.modelData.reverseSort = false;
$scope.headers = {'First Name':'firstName','Last Name':'lastName'}
```

Now, use accordingly:

```
<th ng-repeat="(key,value) in headers"
    ng-click="modelData.orderByField = value; modelData.reverseSort = !modelData.reverseSort">
    {{ key }}
    <span ng-show="modelData.orderByField == value">
        <span ng-show="!modelData.reverseSort"> &#9652</span>
        <span ng-show="modelData.reverseSort"> &#9662</span>
    </span>
</th>
```

Like @VVK answered, there is a problem in your code. Not sure what you are trying to define an `Array` or an `Object`,

Object should be defined like this: `{'First Name':'firstName','Last Name':'lastName'}` (they should start with `{` and end with `}` but not with `[]`);

Change your HTML code to use `modelData` and it will then work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:modelData.orderByField:modelData.reverseSort">
```

Comment: I used your code but, the fields still doesn't get sorted, here is the plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rj1NmrF68GVyRr3Wl0wv?p=preview)

Comment: sorry i didn't save it, check the link now, the fields in each column doesn't get sorted.

Comment: This is not constructive @Koten. Your question is not clear. What you want to achieve? What is not getting sorted?

Comment: On table head click the fields in the column should be sorted by `$scope.headers` value.

Comment: So where is your data in your columns? I'm not seeing anything in your plunkr. Your plunkr still have errors which is not working. Please properly update your plunkr with data which is working so that we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$scope.headers` initialization is wrong. You should define it as

```
$scope.headers={'First Name':'firstName','Last Name':'lastName'}
```